# Python matplotlib overwritten axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot data using multiple subplots on a grid that share the x and y axes while the their respective ticks don't appear every time. But I have some problem with the axes. Let me get into details:

```
#my data
dot_data1
dot_data2
all_data1
all_data2

#make a 2x4 grid
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=True)

#for x axis
x0 = [0]
x  = list(range(1,10000))

#add subplots
for j in range(9):
    ax[j//4][j%4] = fig.add_subplot(2,4,j+1)
    ax[j//4][j%4].plot(x0, dot_data1[j], 'bo')
    ax[j//4][j%4].plot(x0, dot_data2[j], 'go')
    ax[j//4][j%4].plot(x , all_data1[j], 'b-')
    ax[j//4][j%4].plot(x , all_data2[j], 'g-')

#add the ticks
plt.setp(ax, xticks=[0,M], yticks=[i/10 for i in range(3, 11)])
```

Result[image]

You can see that something is wrong. Ideally, I would like to have the xticks only 4 times and the yticks only twice. If not possible, I could go with 8 times as long as it's clear.

Bonus question: How to make the legends and/or the labels to only appear once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your are adding new subplots over the ones you already had.
Try this:

```
#make a 2x4 grid
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axf=ax.flatten()
#for x axis
x0 = [0]
x  = list(range(1,10000))

#add subplots
for j,ax in enumerate(axf):
    ax.plot(x0, dot_data1[j], 'bo')
    ax.plot(x0, dot_data2[j], 'go')
    ax.plot(x , all_data1[j], 'b-')
    ax.plot(x , all_data2[j], 'g-')

#add the ticks
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have already accepted your answer as it fixed my problem. I assume that I will be able to add a general legend by overlapping with a 111 plot and turning off its axes but I ask in case you know any better.

Comment: If I understand correctly you only want one legend, I would just add the legend on the ax you prefer, in the for loop add an if statement for the "j" you want the legend on, and add the legend. if you overlap a new subplot you have the same problem as before, don't you?

Comment: But if I add only one where would it appear? I managed to add a xlabel and ylabel only once with a big plot but no luck for the legend so far.

Comment: It should appear wherever you want. In the for loop label the data you want to show, for example: ax.plot(x , all_data1[j], 'b-', label='all_data1')   and after the loop, just show it on the subplot you want: axf[3].legend()  check legend function if you need to specify where on the subplot you need it.